# Basic Scala/JVM/Akka optimizations for performance on toy SAT solver

Tags: performance, scala, jvm, akka

I am working on a SAT solver using Akka and Scala, and right now it solves a problem that MiniSAT solves in 30 seconds in 6 minutes. So I guess there must be a lot of room for optimization.

But I'm new to Scala, Akka and the JVM, and I bet there are simple and trivial optimizations that I can do -- tuning the JVM heap size, for example. Or maybe there are classes in Scala that I should just avoid.

I would also like to know what tools can be used to profile Scala code line-by-line, or at least method-by-method so I can identify hotspots in the code besides just running hprof.

Akka profiling tools would also be interesting to see as well.

(Sorry for the open-endedness, but it is also useful and very easily searchable using search engines. It should show up on many searches for optimizing Akka on the JVM using Scala.)

The code can be found at http://github.com/roehst/akka-sat.

Some quick implementation details & notes:

- A big problem (SAT) is broken down into 1000 sub-problems
- Each problem is boolean formula represented in CNF as List[List[Int]]
- I use 10 workers with round-robin routing
- Operations on formulas are done with maps and filters over lists with some inlining
- Operations on formulas are defined on an Object, but can be called on formulas using an implicit class

Comment: Too broad for SO. Have you tried on code review for your code optimization? re. tools, it's still not on SO questions scope

Comment: I suggest you use a standard memory allocation and CPU profiler such as JMC first. The heap optimisation helps most when you have it misconfigured.